# When assigning frames in Denavit-Hartenberg (DH) parameters, where do I put the frame on end effector?

Tags: robotic-arm, manipulator, dh-parameters, frame

I have a simple question, for the last link (end effector) I need to estimate the parameters but when I put the reference frames in the center of the end effector, I just don't know.

Last link (end effector) will be from origin of previous link to where? I don't know why I can't understand this one.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments for the DH method:

1. Certain parameters of the frame attached to the first and last links need not be defined. They can be chosen arbitrarily.
2. But generally, make as many parameters as possible to zero.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the theory and applications of robotic manipulations, it is beneficial to **put the origin of the end effector's reference frame at the grasp point**, rather than the geometric center of the end effector itself.

The grasp point is the specific point of the end effector where an object is held or grasped to be manipulated. This point is very relevant because it is directly involved in the robot's interactions, making kinematic analysis, motion planning, and control more intuitive and task-focused.